# Hashsignaling and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently working on a site that uses hashsignaling for page loads. This means there are very few page "loads", but rather lots of ajax content changes and template manipulation.

My question is: how do I track this using Google Analytics? Is there a way I can trigger a GA call in my code that captures the entire url including the hash and any other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you want to represent your site activity in GA, but you could decide what you want to qualify as a "pageview" and call the [_trackPageview()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) method with URL included as a parameter any time that activity happens:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'YOUR URL HERE']);
```

Comment: This could be an option. I shall look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Hashsignaling fire a `hashsignal.hashchange` event on `window` object when a page is updated :

```
$(window).trigger('hashsignal.hashchange', [subhash]);
```

So you can bind a Google Analytics tracking call to this event with something like :

```
$(window).on('hashsignal.hashchange', function(event, subhash){
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', subhash]);
});
```